# Create list of values from os.walk to show names of folders for each path in Python

Tags: python, pandas, os.walk

In my example directory structure, there are 3 folders under `Project` - `das`, `des`, and `dga`. There's also a file `randomfile.xlsx` Within each folder are files and subfolders.

```
Project
 ┣ das
 ┣ des
 ┃ ┣ subfolder_des1
 ┃ ┃ ┗ COM-EL-DES-0002-0.pdf
 ┃ ┗ COM-EL-DES-0001-0.pdf
 ┣ dga
 ┃ ┣ subfolder_dga1
 ┃ ┃ ┗ 3500-ST-DGA-0047-0.pdf
 ┃ ┣ subfolder_dga2
 ┃ ┃ ┣ 3500-ST-DGA-0046-0.pdf
 ┗ randomfile.xlsx
```

My code uses `os.walk` to return a directory tree list of values under the `Project` folder, which I add to a `pandas` DataFrame. e.g.

```
c:/Project/das
c:/Project/des
c:/Project/dga
c:/Project/des/subfolder_des1/
c:/Project/des//subfolder_des1/COM-EL-DES-0002-0.pdf
...
...
```

I'd like to create a second list which specifies the folder a value/path is associated with (e.g. `das`, `des`, and `dga`), but ignore subfolders. Any files in the Project folder would just have the value `Project`.

So resulting dataframe might look like:

```
Path                                                  col2
c:/Project/das                                         das
c:/Project/des                                         des
c:/Project/dga                                         dga
c:/Project/des/subfolder_des1/                         des
c:/Project/des/subfolder_des1/COM-EL-DES-0002-0.pdf    des
c:/Project/randomfile.txt                              Project
c:/Project/dga/subfolder_dga1/                         dga
...
...
```

Just unsure where to start, as I'm not sure I fully understand `os.walk` yet.

My code snippet:

```
def dir_tree(path):
    dir_list = []
    col2_list = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for d in dirs:
            dir_list.append(os.path.join(root, d))
        for f in files:
            dir_list.append(os.path.join(root, f))
    return dir_list, col2_list

def save_to_df(path):
    dir_list, col2_list = dir_tree(path)
    dir_tree_df = pd.DataFrame({"Path" : dir_list, "col2" : col2_list})
```

Edit: Something else to note, I'm only using `dag`, `des` etc as examples. I need to be able to run this script on any path, and it'll need to work out what the folder names are.

An updated script which *might* be doing what I want it to now:

```
def get_folder_name(path_str: str, source_directory: str) -> str:

    path_replace = path_str.replace(source_directory, "")
    path = Path(path_replace)
    parts = path.parts
    
    joined = os.path.join(source_directory, parts[1])
    if os.path.isfile(joined):
        return "root_files"
    else:
        return parts[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` and it's `.name` and `.parent` attributes to create a function that attempts to find the desired folder name:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def get_folder_name(path_str: str) -> str:
    """
    Given a path string, return the name of the desired folder name,
    either "das", "des", "dga", "Project", or None, when not any of the prior.

    Converts the path string to a Path object, and checks if the path.name is
    any of the folders that we want to check for. If not, we move the path
    to the parent instead, and try again.
    """
    path = Path(path_str)
    while path.name:
        if path.name in ("das", "des", "dga", "Project"):
            return path.name
        path = path.parent
    return None

# I've just copied these paths here for convenience, as obviously I don't
# have your file structure for testing. I've created a DataFrame like I'm
# sure you had previously.
paths = [
    "c:/Project/das",
    "c:/Project/des",
    "c:/Project/dga",
    "c:/Project/des/subfolder_des1/",
    "c:/Project/des/subfolder_des1/COM-EL-DES-0002-0.pdf",
    "c:/Project/randomfile.txt",
    "c:/Project/dga/subfolder_dga1/",
    "c:/Other/file.txt", # <- Custom, to show an edge case
]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Paths": paths})

# Here we `apply` get_folder_name on every element of the df["Paths"] column,
# and assign it to a new "Folder" column
df["Folder"] = df["Paths"].apply(get_folder_name)

print(df)
```

This program outputs:

```py
                                               Paths   Folder
0                                     c:/Project/das      das
1                                     c:/Project/des      des
2                                     c:/Project/dga      dga
3                     c:/Project/des/subfolder_des1/      des
4  c:/Project/des/subfolder_des1/COM-EL-DES-0002-...      des
5                          c:/Project/randomfile.txt  Project
6                     c:/Project/dga/subfolder_dga1/      dga
7                                  c:/Other/file.txt     None
```

---

### Edit as a response to the author's comment

If we can simply select the first folder after `Projects`, or alternatively just `Projects` if the path does not contain a folder under `Projects`, then the following snippet should work too, as a replacement of the `get_folder_name` function from above.

```py
def get_folder_name(path_str: str) -> str:
    path = Path(path_str)
    parts = path.parts
    return parts[1] if len(parts) == 3 and path.is_file() else parts[2]
```

Here, we will first separate the `path` into its `parts`, e.g. `path.parts ('c:\\', 'Project', 'des', 'subfolder_des1')`. Then, we will usually pick `parts[2]`, which is `des` in this example, with one very specific exception: If the `parts` tuple is only 3 long **and** the path itself points to a file, instead of a folder. In that case, we have e.g. `c:\Projects\test.txt`. Do note that this requires that `Projects` is at `C:\Projects` and not at `C:\Bla\Projects` etc., as that would require some modifications on the indices.

Note that this function isn't perfect, e.g. the path of `C:\Projects` fails, but this is mostly meant to guide you in the right direction. Feel free to modify this to your likings. Also, here's the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks will try this. Although should clarify I don't actually know if folders will be called `das`, `dga` etc. This was just an example. All I'll have is a path e.g. `c:/Projects` that I pass to my functions and it would need to be up to the code to workout what the folder names are, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ahh, that might even simplify the problem somewhat! Please see my edit.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'll take a look this evening. It should be the case that I'll only be running this on folders that are like `C:/Project` although not 100% sure. And where you say `the path of C:\Prjoects fails` - what did you mean by this?

Comment: Oh, I meant that if the full path string is `C:/Projects`, then `parts` only has length 2, and then `parts[2]` will be out of bounds.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I've slightly amended the code based on what you provided, and I *think* it should now work ever if it were `C:/project/target` etc. Although haven't thoroughly tested it.